# query-replace: ignore events not binded in query-replace-map

Tags: query-replace, query-replace-regexp, events

I have this function:

```el
(defun my-replacements ()
  (interactive)
  (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (query-replace "baz" "quz" nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (query-replace "fred" "thud" nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

If I run it and accidentally type, for example, 'k' during one of the replacements, the function is interrupted, skipping all the remaining replacements.

I know that `query-replace` accepts only events binded in the `query-replace-map` and from the manual I know that:

> Aside from this, any other character exits the query-replace, and is
> then reread as part of a key sequence. Thus, if you type C-k, it exits
> the query-replace and then kills to end of line. In particular, C-g
> simply exits the query-replace.

I would like to circumvent this behavior by ensuring that events not defined in the `query-replace-map` are simply ignored. Is there a way to achieve this?

I thought it could be done with a macro, e.g.:

```el
(with-ignore-qr-unbinded-events
  MY CODE HERE)
```

but I have no idea how to do it.

As a feature request, I would like to add an optional argument to the function so that I can have control over this behavior. Does it make sense to you?

**Edit.** I just realized that a better idea would be using a variable to control this feature I request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```lisp
(defvar my-do-nothing-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (set-char-table-range (nth 1 map) t 'ignore)
    map))

(set-keymap-parent query-replace-map my-do-nothing-map)
```

The proposed solution involves creating a custom keymap called `my-do-nothing-map`. This keymap is configured so that all keyboard events have no associated action, meaning they are ignored.

1. **Creation of `my-do-nothing-map`:** A custom keymap named `my-do-nothing-map` is created using the function `make-keymap`. This keymap serves as a container for key bindings.
2. **Setting Up the Keymap:** Within this custom keymap, the function `set-char-table-range` is used to set a default action for all keyboard events. The `'ignore` value is assigned to every key, indicating that no action should be taken when any key is pressed.
3. **Inheritance from `query-replace-map`:** The keymap `my-do-nothing-map` is set as the parent of `query-replace-map` using the function `set-keymap-parent`. This means that when Emacs looks for a key binding in `query-replace-map` and does not find one, it will then check `my-do-nothing-map` for a binding. Since all keys in `my-do-nothing-map` are configured to be ignored, Emacs effectively skips handling any unbound keys during the execution of `query-replace`.

In summary, this solution ensures that during the execution of `query-replace`, any unintended key presses that are not explicitly bound in `query-replace-map` are ignored, preventing premature interruption of the function due to accidental keystrokes.

`C-g` still works!

Comment: Beautiful! Could you please add a short (or long...) explanation of your code, please?

Comment: I added an explanation of what your code does.

Comment: I approved your edits.  Thanks.