# set-keymap-parent function and let binding of involved keymaps

Tags: keymap, query-replace

I have this content in the buffer:

```latex
\begin{environment}
foo
Some other text here

\end{environment}

\begin{environment}
foo
Some other text here

\end{environment}

\begin{environment}
foo
Some other text here

\end{environment}
```

And I have this code:

```el
(defvar query-replace-parent-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (set-char-table-range (nth 1 map) t 'ignore)
    map))

(set-keymap-parent query-replace-map query-replace-parent-map)
```

That I use to make [query-replace: ignore events not binded in query-replace-map](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80484/15606).

I have also written this function to interactively edit the content of 'environment' (pseudo-`LaTeX` code).

```el
(defun edit-enviroment ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Removes the key-binding from the map:
  (define-key query-replace-parent-map (kbd "m") 'ignore t)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\\begin{environment}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((BEG (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
               (END (copy-marker (search-forward "\\end{environment}" nil t))))

          (save-restriction
            (narrow-to-region BEG END)
            (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))

            (when (input-pending-p)
              (let ((KEY (read-event)))
                (if (eq KEY ?m)
                    (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
                      (read-string
                       "Make any necessary changes and press [Enter] to continue: "))
                  ;; *ELSE*
                  (setq unread-command-events (list KEY)))))))))))
```

In this way if I type "m" `query-replace` interrupts and I can perform some editing in the narrowed buffer.

I'm trying to restore the "m" event to be ignored from `query-replace` at the end of my function?

I tried let-binding `query-replace-parent-map`:

```el
(defun edit-enviroment ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\\begin{environment}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((BEG (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
               (END (copy-marker (search-forward "\\end{environment}" nil t)))
               (query-replace-parent-map (copy-keymap query-replace-parent-map)))
          (define-key query-replace-parent-map (kbd "m") 'ignore t)

          (save-restriction
            (narrow-to-region BEG END)
            (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))

            (when (input-pending-p)
              (let ((KEY (read-event)))
                (if (eq KEY ?m)
                    (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
                      (read-string
                       "Make any necessary changes and press [Enter] to continue: "))
                  ;; *ELSE*
                  (setq unread-command-events (list KEY)))))))))))
```

but in this way the "m" event is ignored from `query-replace` and the `read-string` part of the function is never reached.

I tried let-binding both maps but it works only if I do after the let-binding:

```el
(set-keymap-parent query-replace-map query-replace-parent-map)
```

this way:

```el
(defun edit-enviroment ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\\begin{environment}" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((BEG (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
               (END (copy-marker (search-forward "\\end{environment}" nil t)))
               (query-replace-map (copy-keymap query-replace-map))
               (query-replace-parent-map (copy-keymap query-replace-parent-map)))

          (set-keymap-parent query-replace-map query-replace-parent-map)
          (define-key query-replace-parent-map (kbd "m") 'ignore t)

          (save-restriction
            (narrow-to-region BEG END)
            (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))

            (when (input-pending-p)
              (let ((KEY (read-event)))
                (if (eq KEY ?m)
                    (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
                      (read-string
                       "Make any necessary changes and press [Enter] to continue: "))
                  ;; *ELSE*
                  (setq unread-command-events (list KEY)))))))))))
```

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Can I do it in a simpler way?